# Wininet Caching Wrapper

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, wininet

I am looking for a wininet cache api wrapper that would allow me to manage the cache (cookie and cached files) for an internet explorer based app on a per application instance basis (versus accross all apps like IE/wininet does).

A proxy server would not work for our app.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Squid locally and then use it as the proxy when you call `InternetOpen` etc. in your application.